# Wordpress novo não carrega midias

Tags: wordpress, temas

estou desenvolvendo um tema no wp 4.4.2 e ao tentar fazer upload de uma foto para imagem destacada de um post (thumbnails) eu fico com a seguinte tela:
[image: Subindo Imagem para thumbnail]

Coloquei um quadrado em vermelho no loader que aparece só para ilustrar que não está funcionando.

Para funcionar no meu tema preciso fazer alguma configuração especial?
nos outros temas padrões que vem funciona normalmente.

Comment: Henrique, este é algum problema no código do seu tema. Tente subir uma mídia com o console do firebug (Firefox) ou o nativo do Chrome e veja se tem alguma mensagem de erro na resposta da chamada ajax. Se tiver e não conseguir resolver posta aqui.

Comment: Felipe Elia, como seria subir uma mida pelo console? é a primeira vez que ouço isso, poderia me explicar como faz?

Comment: Suba normalmente, apenas acompanhe o andamento da requisição pelo console

Comment: Consegui subir normalmente, não acusou erros no console, e quando tento subir a imagem ou anexar uma imagem destaca a partir da página de edição de um post tem aquela tela que printei.

Comment: Descobri o erro amigo :) estava no meu functions.php tinha um comentário html antes de abrir o php.